# Does the Ubuntu installer preserve a hybrid MBR?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, mbr

I'm wondering whether the Ubuntu installer, when faced with a hybrid MBR setup, preserves the hybrid MBR as is upon installation, particularly if a partition is deleted/created in the install process?

Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1260204/428527) but the reverse where I actually want my existing hybrid MBR and don't want it overwritten by a protective MBR, or by an arbitrary new hybrid MBR for that matter.

Comment: Since Windows now uses UEFI with gpt, better to have all systems as UEFI. The hybrid was to install old Windows in BIOS mode which required MBR. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html UEFI boot of Windows https://askubuntu.com/questions/650194/repair-windows-boot-loader-after-installing-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro You can install Ubuntu using Something Else in UEFI boot mode to a gpt partition.

Comment: @oldfred I agree that I'd prefer that, but macOS Mojave's Bootcamp creates a hybrid setup when installing Windows 10 on a 2012 MacBook Air. I'm working under the assumption that it does this for a reason. The only explanation for this I've come across is that it's because 2012 MacBooks are not fully UEFI compliant, and that perhaps some power management might not work properly in EFI mode (?)

Comment: Do not really know Mac, and it seems every year's version is different. iMac 13, 2 (late 2012) 27"  It Just Works! 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425170

Comment: @oldfred I think they're only referring to Ubuntu working, which I don't doubt. The problem is that Windows will stop booting if the MBR is regenerated and decides to exclude the Windows partition or doesn't preserve the right flag (probably), or is replaced with a protective MBR (Windows refuses to boot from GPT).

Comment: Not sure how BootCamp works, but Windows in BIOS mode needs MBR to be Windows boot loader, boot flag on primary NTFS partition with its boot files. It often was a separate Boot partition since Windows 7, but can be just one NTFS if all boot files are in it. Not sure if this will tell anything or not: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I understood exactly, did you want me to run boot repair even though I don't have any boot problems? What are we trying to accomplish with it? I.e. what are we looking for in that report?

Comment: I only suggest the report from Boot-Repair for information. I do not know Mac, so really cannot help but others that see the details may be able to.

Comment: @oldfred The question is only about the Ubuntu installer though, not Mac.